# How to print a list without [ , '' in python

Tags: python

I want to print

```
*IBM is a trademark of the International Business Machine Corporation.
```

in python instead of this

```
['*', 'I', 'B', 'M', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'r', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'k', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'I', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'a', 'l', ' ', 'B', 'u', 's', 'i', 'n', 'e', 's', 's', ' ', 'M', 'a', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'C', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'o', 'r', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', '.']
```

My code:

```
n=str(input())
l=len(n)
m=[' ']*l
for i in range(l):
    m[i]=chr(ord(n[i])-7)
print(m)
```

Comment: Why is this a list in the first place? Where is it coming from?

Comment: `print(*your_lst, sep='')` if you're on Python 3.

Comment: BTW, you are probably getting those downvotes because 1. you didn't show us your own code attempt, and 2. you haven't responded to the comment asking you to explain where this list is coming from. The best solution probably involves fixing stuff upstream so you get the data as a string instead of a list in the first place.

Comment: Code added @PM2Ring :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your list is:

```
this_is_a_list = ['*', 'I', 'B', 'M', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'r', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'k', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'I', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'a', 'l', ' ', 'B', 'u', 's', 'i', 'n', 'e', 's', 's', ' ', 'M', 'a', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'C', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'o', 'r', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', '.']
```

use `join`:

```
''.join(this_is_a_list)
```

*extended*:

<s>in case you plan to use the `string` in the future:</s> This method is extremely inefficient, but I'm going to leave it here as a showcase of what *not* to do: (Thanks to @PM 2Ring)

```
# BAD EXAMPLE, AVOID THIS METHOD
final_word = ""
for i in xrange(len(this_is_a_list)):
    final_word = final_word + this_is_a_list[i]

print final_word
```

> further edited, *thanks to* @kuro

```
final_word = ''.join(this_is_a_list)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `s = ''.join(this_is_a_list)` do the job?

Comment: What kuro said. The second version is _extremely_ inefficient. In fact it's a good example of how _not_ to do it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`

```
x = ['*', 'I', 'B', 'M', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'r', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'k', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'I', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'a', 'l', ' ', 'B', 'u', 's', 'i', 'n', 'e', 's', 's', ' ', 'M', 'a', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'C', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'o', 'r', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', '.']
print(''.join(x))
'*IBM is a trademark of the International Business Machine Corporation.'
```

Comment: error:    ''.join(x)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: @ToufiqueImam "".join(x) note the 2 quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

The sensible way to do this is to use `.join`. And to perform the decoding operation you can loop directly over the chars of the input string rather than using indices.

```
s = input('> ')
a = []
for u in s:
    c = chr(ord(u) - 7)
    a.append(c)
print(''.join(a))
```

**demo**

```
> 1PIT'pz'h'{yhklthyr'vm'{ol'Pu{lyuh{pvuhs'I|zpulzz'Thjopul'Jvywvyh{pvu5
*IBM is a trademark of the International Business Machine Corporation.
```

We can make this much more compact by using a list comprehension.

```
s = input('> ')
print(''.join([chr(ord(u)-7) for u in s]))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this one

```
to_print = ['*', 'I', 'B', 'M', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'r', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'r', 'k', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'I', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', 'n', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'a', 'l', ' ', 'B', 'u', 's', 'i', 'n', 'e', 's', 's', ' ', 'M', 'a', 'c', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'e', ' ', 'C', 'o', 'r', 'p', 'o', 'r', 'a', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', '.']
word = ''
for i in range(len(to_print)):
    word = word + to_print[i]

print (word)
```

Comment: Over the top code when all that is required is the recognised Pythonic way of doing things: join()

Comment: See my comment on TheDarkKnight's answer. This is a very un-Pythonic way to solve the problem. In Python we normally loop directly over list items, rather than looping indirectly via indices: it's more efficient & produces cleaner code. In some cases you _do_ need the indices as well as the items, but in that situation you can generally use `enumerate`.